# Reading with setw: to eof or not to eof?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, iostream, std

Consider the following simple example

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string str = "string";
  istringstream is(str);
  is >> setw(6) >> str;
  return is.eof();
}
```

At the first sight, since the explicit width is specified by the `setw` manipulator, I'd expect the `>>` operator to finish reading the string after successfully extracting the requested number of characters from the input stream. I don't see any immediate reason for it to try to extract the seventh character, which means that I don't expect the stream to enter `eof` state.

When I run this example under MSVC++, it works as I expect it to: the stream remains in good state after reading. However, in GCC the behavior is different: the stream ends up in `eof` state.

The language standard, it gives the following list of completion conditions for this version of `>>` operator

> - n characters are stored;
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;
> - isspace(c,is.getloc()) is true for the next available input character c.

Given the above, I don't see any reason for the `>>` operator to drive the stream into the `eof` state in the above code.

However, this is what the `>>` operator [implementation in GCC library](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/libstdc%2B%2B-api-4.5/a00755_source.html#l00996) looks like

```
...
__int_type __c = __in.rdbuf()->sgetc();

while (__extracted < __n
       && !_Traits::eq_int_type(__c, __eof)
       && !__ct.is(__ctype_base::space,
                   _Traits::to_char_type(__c)))
{
  if (__len == sizeof(__buf) / sizeof(_CharT))
  {
    __str.append(__buf, sizeof(__buf) / sizeof(_CharT));
    __len = 0;
  }
  __buf[__len++] = _Traits::to_char_type(__c);
  ++__extracted;
  __c = __in.rdbuf()->snextc();
}
__str.append(__buf, __len);

if (_Traits::eq_int_type(__c, __eof))
  __err |= __ios_base::eofbit;
__in.width(0);
...
```

As you can see, at the end of each successful iteration, it attempts to prepare the next `__c` character for the next iteration, even though the next iteration might never occur. And after the cycle it analyzes the last value of that `__c` character and sets the `eofbit` accordingly.

So, my question is: triggering the `eof` stream state in the above situation, as GCC does - is it legal from the standard point of view? I don't see it explicitly specified in the document. Is both MSVC's and GCC's behavior compliant? Or is only one of them behaving correctly?

Comment: I don't think the specification requires the checking of the list to short-circuit (or even be in that order), and if it's not required to short circuit then the third item (checking `isspace` for the next available input character) would require it to prepare the next character.

Comment: [libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0c5d41b6d1944c5) agrees with MSVC.

Comment: I don't have standard text to back this up, but my understanding is that it's optional whether reading the last character sets `eofbit`. (Trying to read after reading the last character definitely does set it).

Answer (score 2):

The definition for that particular `operator>>` is not relevant to the setting of the `eofbit`, as it only describes when the operation terminates, but not what triggers a particular bit.

The description for the `eofbit` in the standard (draft) says:

> eofbit  - indicates that an input operation reached the end of an input sequence;

I guess here it depends on how you want to interpret "reached". Note that gcc implementation correctly does not set `failbit`, which is defined as

> failbit - indicates that an input operation failed to read the expected characters, or
>   that an output operation failed to generate the desired characters.

So I think `eofbit` does not necessarily mean that the end of file impeded the extractions of any new characters, just that the end of file has been "reached".

I can't seem to find a more accurate description for "reached", so I guess that would be implementation defined. If this logic is correct, then both MSVC and gcc behaviors are correct.

---

EDIT: In particular, it seems that `eofbit` gets set when `sgetc()` would return `eof`. This is described both in the `istreambuf_iterator` section and in the `basic_istream::sentry` section. So now the question is: when is the current position of the stream allowed to advance?

---

FINAL EDIT: It turns out that probably g++ has the correct behavior.

Every character scan passes through `<locale>`, in order to allow different character sets, money formats, time descriptions and number formats to be parsed. While there does not seem to be a through description on how the `operator>>` works for strings, there are very specific descriptions on how `do_get` functions for numbers, time and money are supposed to operate. You can find them from page 687 of the draft forward.

All of these start off by reading a `ctype` (the "global" version of a character, as read through locales) from a `istreambuf_iterator` (for numbers, you can find the call definitions at page 1018 of the draft). Then the ctype is processed, and finally the iterator is advanced.

So, in general, this requires the internal iterator to always point to the next character after the last one read; if that was not the case you could in theory extract more than you wanted:

```
string str = "strin1";
istringstream is(str);
is >> setw(6) >> str;
int x;
is >> x;
```

If the current character for `is` after the extraction for `str` was not on the `eof`, then the standard would require that `x` gets the value 1, since for numeric extraction the standard explicitly requires that the iterator is advanced after the first read.

Since this does not make much sense, and given that all complex extractions described in the standard behave in the same way, it makes sense that for strings the same would happen. Thus, as the pointer for `is` after reading 6 characters falls on the `eof`, the `eofbit` needs to be set.

Comment: Extracting or not a character has no effect on `eof`. The `eofbit` is set when `sgetc` returns `eof`; equivalently when `*it` returns `eof`, where `it` is the internal stream iterator. `operator>>` *does* stop after extracting `n` characters. Since now the stream iterator points to the character after the ones extracted, and that character is `eof`, it sets `eofbit`.